# vimscript: identifying maps in groovy indent file

Tags: vim, groovy, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm using [this script](https://github.com/vim-scripts/groovyindent-unix) as a groovy indent file.  It works great, with one exception: it doesn't indent built-in maps.  For example, I would like to see this:

```
def map = [
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2'
]
```

But what I see is this:

```
def map = [
key1: 'value1',
key2: 'value2'
]
```

How can I adjust the script so that it properly identifies maps? I tried changing lines 105, 125, and 132 to include `[` and `]` in addition to the `{` and `}`, but that didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Groovy Indent file you posted is just an addition to the C indent file.
So you won't find the indentation for a opening bracket there.

Instead of modifying a case there you have to write your own:

```
if getline(prev) =~# '[' && getline(prev) !~# ']' && getline(v:lnum) !~# ']' && getline(v:lnum) !~# ':$'
  let theIndent = indent(prev) + &sw
endif
```

This should work more or less if inserted in line 73. But you probably will have to do some fine-tuning. Writing a correct working indentation is in my experience the hardest part of a language plugin. So it wouldn't hurt if you read a tutorial first.

**Update**

The problem you have with a `,` at the end comes from this block:

```
  " find start of previous line, in case it was a continuation line
  let lnum = SkipGroovyBlanksAndComments(v:lnum - 1)
  let prev = lnum
  while prev > 1
    let next_prev = SkipGroovyBlanksAndComments(prev - 1)
    if getline(next_prev) !~ ',\s*$'  " <---------lines ending with , are skipped
      break
    endif
    let prev = next_prev
  endwhile
```

Now I don't know groovy enough to ensure you that it will have no sideeffects, but you could modify my first solution above to use `SkipGroovyBlanksAndComments(v:lnum -1)` instead of `prev`

Comment: that doesn't seem to have worked. I'm still getting the same no-indent

Comment: try to change the middle line to `return indent(prev) + &sw`. Furthermore you can debug your indent function with `:breakadd func GetGroovyIndent` and then use `s` to step througth the code. As said, the indent function is not trivial at all, and a lot can go wrong.

Comment: I've got the manual auto-indenter (`=` key) working by using [this](https://pastebin.com/S61iVuV4).  Only thing I don't know now is how to get it to automatically unindent when I close the `]`, without having to exit insert mode and hit `=``=`, like it does when you close a `}`.  Any idea? I imagine that functionality probably comes from the C file.

Comment: Had the same problem look here https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13762/autoindent-different-from-manuall-indenting

Comment: another issue. This will properly indent the first line of the map, but not the second, for example, the autoindenter now gives me [this](https://pastebin.com/yYzSMYgK). But if I leave out the trailing comma, I get it properly indented, like [this](https://pastebin.com/uWFwFmKm)

Comment: also, I used the breakpoint thing to debug, and I couldn't quit the debugger. I had to kill the entire process

Comment: First your debugger. Press `c` to continue then use `:breakdel` ( you may need `breaklist` too) to remove the breakpoint. Your second Problem has a lot of possible solutions. I will have a look at which is the best, but it could be monday until I have Time.

Comment: that caused an infinite loop it looks like.

Comment: which function have you modified? You should modify the first 3 lines of code in my answer, not the second function

Comment: ah, right. I modified the second.

I'm not sure why, but it's working now. I must have modified something before you responded and not remembered. Either way, thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm a little confused here, what's the final solution? What function do we need to modify and replace or insert what? Could it be possible to summarize the final solution?

Comment: @rboy The "final" answer are my first 3 lines of code, but with every `prev` replaced with `SkipGroovyBlanksAndComments(v:lnum -1)`. Of course you should save that in a variable.

Comment: Okay I tried that it didn't work, it keeps adding an extra tab in each new line

Comment: @rboy
Sorry It has been a while since the answer I am not sure any more, could be wrong. But are you sure you inserted the function in the right place? See my comment about debugging it, check if the test is reached at all. With ah bit of debugging it should be possible to solve this issue. Also have a look if the indent file has changed in the meantime,

Answer (score 0):

Without any new text-objects see more it [here](https://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/10/17/vim-text-objects-the-definitive-guide/)
Let's say you are at first line of the code, you can do:

```
$>i[

$ ......... jump to the end of the line
> ......... indent
i[ ........ inner [
```

Placing [textobjvim_wellle_viml](http://codegist.net/snippet/viml/textobjvim_wellle_viml) in your `~/.vimrc` you can do something like:

```
>in[
```

It stantds for: `indent inner next [`

Comment: This allows me to indent manually it looks like. I'm trying to get the groovy indent file to automatically indent the insides of the map.